# How to detect an event in a Border control generated by a TextBlock embeded in the Border?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a Border control that "hosts" a TextBlock:

```
                <Border x:Name="VideosBorder" 
                    BorderBrush="Black" 
                    BorderThickness="1" 
                    Background="#FF77FF83" 
                    Tapped="Border_Tapped">

                <TextBlock x:Name="tbVideos" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Text="Videos" 
                           TextAlignment="Center" 
                           FontWeight="Bold" 
                           FontSize="13.333" 
                           Foreground="Black" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Tapped="Border_Tapped"/>
            </Border>


    private void Border_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        if ( ( sender == VideosBorder ) || ( sender == tbVideos ) )
            {
            ...
            }
        else if ( ( sender == ImagesBorder ) || ( sender == tbImages ) )
            {
             ...
           }
        else if ( ( sender == ArticlesBorder ) || ( sender == tbArticles ) )
            {
            ...
            }
        else
            {
            ...
            }

        ...
        }
```

I would like to detect any Tapped event on all the area of the Border control. However, if the TextBlock is Tapped, the Border does not detect the Tapped event. I solved the issue by implementing two Tapped events (one on the Border and one on the TextBlock). Can it be implemented with only detecting the Border Tapped events and having events on the TextBlock to bubble to the Border?

Thx.

Comment: Might as well just trade your `TextBlock` for a `TextBox` template styled the way you want it and without the VisualStates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add only  e.Handled = true; on Border_Tapped event.Hope this Helps

```
<Border x:Name="VideosBorder" Height="35" Width="200" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF77FF83" Tapped="Border_Tapped">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbVideos" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Videos" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>

  private void Border_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        VideosBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
    }
```